# Custom fonts in pdf

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, dompdf

I want to render two custom fonts in my commerce pdf, but it does not work.

I tried it in several ways: I use the @font-face and used the path as well the URL and also put the font files in different locations: in /web/assets/fonts, in /storage/fonts and directly in the dompdf/lib/fonts ... nothing works! And I used several fonts.

Any idea? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I loaded the fonts with the load_font.php script (dompdf/utils) and that's how it works.

(See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18066618/10228942)

Comment: Are you able to expand on this answer at all? I downloaded load_font.php here: https://github.com/dompdf/utils/blob/master/load_font.php but am having trouble running it successfully. Not sure how to configure the following within load_font:

// 1. [Required] Point to the composer or dompdf autoloader
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

Comment: @Tchick Have you read the linked answer? When you saved the load_font.php in the dompdf folder, you have to change the path to "../autoload.php"

Comment: thank you for this - I got it working now (the path to autoload.php was incorrect as you suggest).

Comment: You're welcome!